# Write the general term of the periodic sequence $1$, $-1$, $-1$, $1$, $-1$, $-1$, $1$, ..., as $(-1)^{g(n)}$ or other closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to put mathematically sequence that changes sign like:

$n = 0\quad f = 1$

$n = 1 \quad f = -1$

$n = 2 \quad f = -1$

$n = 3 \quad f = 1$

$n = 4 \quad f = -1$

$n = 5 \quad f = -1$

$n = 6 \quad f = 1$
.....

In the form of (-1)^(something) or similar analytical expression.

Comment: Is there closed form analytical expression ?

Comment: @Anonymous That is the closed form expression for the sequence $\{ 1, -1,  1, -1, \dots \}$, which is not your sequence.

Comment: This is easy if the use of modulus is permitted.

Answer (score 9):

This formula works:
$$f(n)=-\frac13+\frac43\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3n\right)$$
[Here's a graph of what that looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeJwH.jpg)

Since the sum of any three consecutive values is $-1$, it satisfies this recurrence relation:
$$f(x+2)=-f(x+1)-f(x)-1$$
It also satisfies the recurrence relation $f(x+3)=f(x)$, though that's less interesting.

(Geometrically, think of a circle of radius $4/3$ centered on the point $(-1/3,0)$. This circle passes through the three equidistant points $(1,0)$, $(-1,2/\sqrt3)$, and $(-1,-2/\sqrt3)$ (they form the corners of an equilateral triangle inscribed in the circle). The function $f$ alternately takes the $x$-coordinate of each of these points.)

Answer (score 8):

\begin{align}
a_1 &=  1 \\
a_2 &= -1 \\
a_n &= a_{n-1}a_{n-2}
\end{align}

Using a product recurrence relation, we have

$$
a_n = a_2^{F_{n-1}}a_1^{F_{n-2}}
$$

Where $F_k$ is the $k$'th Fibonacci number. Given a closed form for $F_k$, we can simplify $a_n$.

$$
F_k = \frac{(1 + \sqrt{5})^k - (1 - \sqrt{5})^k}{2^k\sqrt{5}}
$$

$$
a_n = (-1)^{F_{n-1}} = (-1)^{\frac{(1 + \sqrt{5})^{n-1} - (1 - \sqrt{5})^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}\sqrt{5}}}
$$

This was solved so that the starting index of the sequence was $1$. If you want to start at $0$, we simply shift the index by $+1$.

$$
a_n = (-1)^{F_{n}} = (-1)^{\frac{(1 + \sqrt{5})^{n} - (1 - \sqrt{5})^{n}}{2^{n}\sqrt{5}}}
$$

---

Using Euler's Formula, we can get a far more (or less) elegant solution:

$$
a_n = (-1)^{F_n} = \cos(\pi F_n) + i\sin(\pi F_n) = e^{i\pi F_n}
$$

Comment: LOL. (+1) ${}{}$

Comment: Upon closer inspection, 
$$
a_n = (-1)^{F_n} = e^{i\pi F_n} = \cos(\pi F_n) + i\sin(\pi F_n)
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$
{1 \over 3}\left[4\cos\left({2n\pi \over 3}\right) - 1\right]\,,\qquad
n = 0,1,2,\ldots
$$

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility (closer to the $(-1)^k$ that you claim to have played with) is:
$$
(-1)^{1+\left\lfloor\frac{2(k-1)}{3}\right\rfloor}
$$

(and I won't be surprised if I managed to get one of the shifts wrong).

Comment: This seems like imaginary.

Comment: @Anonymous - that $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function - the greatest integer $\le$ to what is inside. So the exponent is always an integer, and the value is always $1$ or $-1$. However, it could be simplified to $(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{2k+1}3\right\rfloor}$

Comment: I chose not to simplify the expression as I believed having both shifts made it a little clearer how I got from $(-1)^{\lfloor2k/3\rfloor}$ which I believe is a quite natural thing to try. I should probably have written something about that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a negative result: $f(n)$ cannot be written in the form
$$ f(n) = (-1)^{g(n)} $$
where $g$ is a polynomial function.

The relevant condition on $g$ is that its values form the period 3 sequence

$$ g(n) \equiv 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, \ldots \pmod{2} $$

The *difference* sequence of a sequence is defined by $\Delta h(n) = h(n+1) - h(n)$. We can compute the differences of $g$:

$$ \Delta g(n) \equiv 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, \ldots \pmod{2} $$
$$ \Delta^2 g(n) \equiv 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, \ldots \pmod{2} $$
$$ \Delta^3 g(n) \equiv 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, \ldots \pmod{2} $$

and so forth. If $g$ were a polynomial function, then by taking enough differences we would arrive at the zero sequence; but that clearly cannot happen.

Comment: This proves is that $g(n)$ cannot be a polynomial. An analytic function is not limited to this, it can be any function described by a convergent power series. Polynomials are such functions, but not all such functions are polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

with $r = -\frac12 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$

$$a_k = \frac{2(r^k + \overline{r^k} ) -1}{3} $$

should work.

I'm sorry for posting a wrong answer before.

Comment: That doesn't work, the desired sequence is $1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1, \cdots $ and your sequence is $1,-1,-1, 1, 1,-1,-1, 1,1,-1,-1, 1,\dots $

Comment: r=(-1+1i*sqrt(2))/2;
k=[0 1 2 3 4];(2*(r.^k+(conj(r.^k)))-1)/3

ans =

    1.0000   -1.0000   -0.6667    0.5000   -0.9167 Matlab

Comment: @Anonymous r = (-1 + sqrt(3)*i)/2, sorry

Comment: awesome thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The sign changes every 3 steps. So basically you've got a + if $n = 0$ and then $n = 3$ and $n = 6$ etc. Therefore it's an alternating sequence given as such: $a_n = 1$ if $n$ mod $3 = 0 $ and $-1$ otherwise.

Edit: The answer using the floor function was wrong as pointed by Erick Wong.
Here is another way to write down the general term of the sequence : 
$$a_n = (-1)^{\mathbb{1}_{n \ mod   \ 3 \ \neq \ 0}}.$$

Comment: Is there closed form analytical expression ?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: @bgsk Your exponent certainly looks like it has period $4$, not $3$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is $1$ except for integers, where it vanishes. If we scale it to miss only $3$-integers and put as exponent onto $-1$:
$$
(-1)^{\lceil n/3 \rceil - \lfloor n/3 \rfloor}
$$
or similarly, but with the floor function only:
$$
(-1)^{\lfloor -n/3 \rfloor + \lfloor n/3 \rfloor}
$$
we get your desired sequence for $n=0$, $1$, $2\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

$$\ (-1)^{n^2\,\rm mod\,3}\ $$

Answer (score 2):

If you allow yourself other roots of unity, you can use the *discrete fourier transform*.

I presume you want the sequence to have period $3$. So, we use the cube root of unity $\zeta = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}$. The DFT $\hat{f}$ is given by

$$ \hat{f}(n) = \sum_{k=0}^2 f(k) \zeta^{kn} $$

which we can tabulate as

- $\hat{f}(0) = -1$
- $\hat{f}(1) = 2$
- $\hat{f}(2) = 2$

Then, we can recover $f$ by

$$ f(n) = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=0}^2 \hat{f}(k) \zeta^{-kn} $$

which works out to

$$ f(n) = \frac{1}{3} \left(-1 + 2 \zeta^n + 2 \zeta^{-n} \right) $$

which can be expressed in a variety of forms; e.g. since $\zeta = \exp(2 \pi i / 3)$, we have

$$ \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi n}{3} \right) = \frac{\zeta^n + \zeta^{-n}}{2} $$

and thus

$$ f(n) = \frac{1}{3} \left( -1 + 4 \cos\left( \frac{2 \pi n}{3} \right) \right) $$

More generally, you could solve this by picking any three linearly independent functions with period $3$, then solving a system of equations to recover what coefficients you need on them to construct $f$; the DFT is just a direct way to obtain such a solution when the three functions are $1$, $\zeta$, and $\zeta^2$.

Answer (score 1):

A meta-answer: if you already have the sequence $0,1,1,0,1,1\ldots$, then you may take the power of $-1,$ but you actually don't need exponentiation at all (similarly for other periodical sequences):
\begin{align}
a_n &=1 - 2(n^2 \bmod 3)\\
&=1 - 2n^2 + 6\lfloor n^2/3\rfloor\\
&=1 - 2\cdot \lvert (n-1) {\bmod} 3 -1\rvert\\
&= 1 - 2(\lceil n/3 \rceil - \lfloor n/3 \rfloor) \\
&= 1- 2\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{n: \, 3\not\mid n\}}\\
&=\ldots
\end{align}
which I think is neater. Also:
$$
a_n= (-1)^{2k+1 \bmod 3}
$$